# openssl-1.0.1e compiling on Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, compiling, make, openssl

I am compiling [OpenSSL-1.0.1e](http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz) on Debian Lenny (armv4 architecture). I have been following the instruction on http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssl.html to compile the source code. `make` and `make test` are successfully completed. I wonder how I should continue the compiling the file.

Should I do `make install` or stick to the instruction and do

```
make MANDIR=/usr/share/man MANSUFFIX=ssl install &&
install -dv -m755 /usr/share/doc/openssl-1.0.1e  &&
cp -vfr doc/*     /usr/share/doc/openssl-1.0.1e
```

EDIT: I did both of the methods but I still have the old version of the openssl. do I need to copy the `openssl` binary and paste it to a specific directory (e.g., `/usr/bin`) to replace the new binary with the old one? How do I suppose to update the program?

EDIT2: `make test` output:
ALL TESTS SUCCESSFUL.

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/test'
OPENSSL_CONF=apps/openssl.cnf util/opensslwrap.sh version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Jun 10 05:08:05 UTC 2013
platform: dist
options:  bn(32,32) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,2,long) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -O
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
```

`make install` output:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/engines'
making install in apps...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/apps'
installing openssl
installing CA.sh
installing CA.pl
installing tsget
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/apps'
making install in test...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/test'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/test'
making install in tools...
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/openssl-1.0.1e/tools'
installing libcrypto.a
installing libssl.a
cp libcrypto.pc /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig
chmod 644 /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
cp libssl.pc /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig
chmod 644 /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
cp openssl.pc /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig
chmod 644 /usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is: Your openssl debian package is placed on `/usr/bin, /usr/lib, /usr/share/man`, and the compiled one is entirely inside `/usr/local/{bin,share,lib}`. Your shell finds the `/usr/bin` binaries first(from the package) and executes it.

You'll need to use the `./config --prefix=/usr` while configuring your OpenSSL, but this could overwrite your binaries installed through apt and it could break you system. A better more correct way to compile is to use [debian source packages](http://wiki.debian.org/SourcePackage).

Is there any feature that you want that is not compiled on the stable version(http://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/openssl)?

Comment: nwilder: I already compiled the source by `config --prefix=/usr `. I also did `apt-get --purge remove openssl` then recompiled the source. After `make install`, if I tyoe openssl, the terminal outputs `openssl: No such file or directory`. Do you know why make install does not work? The device that I am using does not support squeeze or wheezy because of the processor issue, I can only use Lenny on it

Comment: This could be a missing configuration file. Have you created the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf, or there exists a /etc/ssl ?

Cheers

Comment: There is only `certs` folder inside /etc/ssl. Inside the certs folder, there is only one certificate.. I used the same config options as written on http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssl.html         however, `/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf` exists

Comment: the `openssl` is located on `/usr/local/ssl/bin`, when I execute it, it shows that it is the correct version. however, when I run openssl on the terminal, it shows "-bash: /usr/bin/openssl: No such file or directory" (I purge removed the old openssl). what file do I need to edit so that openssl will be executed when I type it on the terminal?

Comment: What about if you add /usr/local/ssl/bin to your $PATH environment variable?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Edit the user .bash_profile(it could be /root/.bash_profile or /home/your_user/.bash_profile) and add the following line:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ssl/bin`